# How can I get the aws profile id from the aws configure sso command

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, aws-cli, tee

As part of a bash script to automate connecting to our postgres instance I need to configure the aws cli tool and set the AWS_PROFILE variable. The command outputs this in the final line of its output.

The problem is that `aws configure sso` is interactive so I can't just dump the output in a variable. So I have done the following:

```
AWS_OUTPUT=$(aws configure sso | tee /dev/tty)
export AWS_PROFILE=$(tail -1 <<< "$AWS_OUTPUT" | cut -d' ' -f5)
```

This works, but its hard to use because every time I press any key while `aws configure sso` is running a carriage return is also inserted and the output is very confusing (though barely usable).

Is there a better way to get the profile id? Or a way to prevent the carriage return issue?

Comment: AWS_PROFILE holds just the name of the profile that you want to use (local to your machine). This is the same as a name that you use in aws configure (sso in this example).  The profile is something that should be set once, not every time (if your assuming a role, aws cli can help with that as well)

Comment: @Caldazar are you sure you aren't confusing it with the sso session name? That one seems to be local to my computer, but the AWS_PROFILE variable that subsequent aws commands require is determined by the account I select at the end of the aws configure sso workflow